# Solving $ (\dot{x}+1)^3=(\dot{x}-x)^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following differential equation I want to find the general solution and all critical solutions
$$ (\dot{x}+1)^3=(\dot{x}-x)^2 $$
I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the critical points, set $\dot{x} = 0$ and find the values of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of implicit differential equations has the systematic ansatz to reparametrize $x$ and $t$ with a new parameter $p$, $T(p)=t$, $X(p)=x(T(p))$. The new parameter is fixed by $\dot x=p$.

Then you get the system $X'(p)=p\cdot T'(p)$ and $(p+1)^3=(X(p)+p)^2$. This can now be solved for $X(p)$, $X'(p)$, then $T'(p)$, which then is to be integrated.

Comment: So I got as solution:    
$t=\ln{|p|} \pm \frac32 \ln{|\frac{\sqrt{p+1}-1}{\sqrt{p+1}+1}|} \pm 3 \sqrt{p+1} + C $,    

$x=p\pm (p+1)^{3/2}$

Is there a nice way to check this?

Comment: One way is to write up enough computation steps so that the "forward" computation can be checked. (You can add the computation as addendum to your question or write a new answer for that.) In "reverse" you can only check if the derivative of $t$ fits, $x$ is obviously correct.